# How to center value vertically on each subsection of a single stacked bar plot in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

I want to create a stacked bar plot with a single bar, and I would like that each value is shown on the graph, in the middle of the corresponding section.

This [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDc0U.png)is what I get and I have no idea on how to move them. It's weird because they are upside down too.

This is my code:

```
sk <- sk %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = c(A, B,C, D, E, F), 
               names_to = "Variable", values_to = "Value")

sk <- sk %>%
  group_by(Variable) %>%
  mutate(cumulative = cumsum(Value) - (Value / 2))

ggplot(data = sk, aes(x = variable, y = Value, fill = Variable)) +
  geom_bar(position = "stack", stat = "identity") +
  xlab("") + ylab("") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.position = "right") +
geom_text(aes(y = cumulative, label = Value))
```

Comment: Can you use `dput(sk)` to show us what the input data looks like? Your `ggplot()` call refers to both "Variable" and "variable" is that intentional?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to try to work out the cumulative position of the stacked labels. Simply put `position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)` inside your `geom_text` call.

Also note that `geom_bar(stat = "identity")` is just a long way of writing `geom_col`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

sk %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = c(A, B, C, D, E, F), 
               names_to = "Variable", values_to = "Value") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = "", y = Value, fill = Variable)) +
  geom_col(position = "stack") +
  geom_text(position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), aes(label = Value)) +
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

I might also point out that from both a data viz and aesthetic point of view, a stacked single bar isn't the best way to show your data here. Compare, for example:

```r
sk %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = c(A, B, C, D, E, F), 
               names_to = "Variable", values_to = "Value") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Variable, y = Value, fill = Variable)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(aes(label = Value), nudge_y = 2) +
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.position = 'none')
```

[image]

Which is tidier, easier to read, easier to interpret and nicer to look at.

---

**Data approximation inferred from image in question**

```r
sk <- data.frame(A = 38, B = 226, C = 752, D = 1692, E = 3045, F = 5977)/100
```

Comment: Thank you @Allan Cameron ! I used a stacked bar plot because they are different shares of something, they do not add up to 100% because there are overlaps that I do not know. Do you think it would still make sense to use a normal bar plot?

Comment: @Abaco it might make _more_ sense to have a normal bar chart if you do not know the size of the overlap. A stacked bar suggests that you know the non-overlapping proportion of each.

Comment: Hey @Allan Cameron that's great thanks! Would you be able to help me to add the % symbol after each number (e.g. 59.77%, 30.55%, etc.) or on the scale on the vertical axis?